# autocompletetextview doesn't suggest what I want

Tags: android, autocompletetextview

I am loading around 20,000 strings from a xml, besides that it takes very much time until the app really makes me a suggestion, when I type `Cra` it shows me the first suggestion `Valea Crabului` and i have `Craiova` in the strings but that is suggested later.

How can a `AutoCompleteTextView` suggest me only the words that match the whole word ?

Comment: are you using a custom filter? can you post some code?

Comment: @OvidiuLatcu I am not using a custom filter should I implement one ?

Comment: You mean Craiova is not suggested on "Cra" input? Not even when you scroll down in the suggestions list? Maybe the size of the array could be an issue.

Comment: It seems the AutoComplete working based on Second name as in Default Contacts. Second Name starts with Cra so it is showing it as first element

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using `ArrayAdapter` for your `AutoCompleteTextView`, than here you can see default implementation of the filter for `ArrayAdapter` https://github.com/android/platform_frameworks_base/blob/master/core/java/android/widget/ArrayAdapter.java

From the inner class `ArrayFilter` of `ArrayAdapter`:

```
for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
                final T value = values.get(i);
                final String valueText = value.toString().toLowerCase();

                // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                    newValues.add(value);
                } else {
                    final String[] words = valueText.split(" ");
                    final int wordCount = words.length;

                    // Start at index 0, in case valueText starts with space(s)
                    for (int k = 0; k < wordCount; k++) {
                        if (words[k].startsWith(prefixString)) {
                            newValues.add(value);
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

You see filter doesn't sort matched items by relevance you require, you have to write your own filter for your adapter.

Instead

```
                // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                    newValues.add(value);
                } else {
```

you may need to use

```
                // First match against the whole, non-splitted value
                if (valueText.startsWith(prefixString)) {
                    newValues.add(0, value);
                } else {
```

so your filter will add values starting with your suggested string at the top of results as the most relevant filter result.